# Yet another wifi problem

Tags: networking

Ubuntu 16.04, lenovo ideapad 110, rtl8821ae, 
Networking is enabled, wired network  is OK but Wifi networks are missing. Tried most of the answers above with no luck.
Response to "iwconfig" 
enp3s0    no wireless extensions. 
lo        no wireless extensions

Wireless-info.tx-: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26178402/plain/

Comment: Please remove the incorrect driver: `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` Reboot and let us see a new wireless script.

Comment: Thank, you, after : sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26193962/